# sum() of column by distinct() id column

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
select 
    sum(leads.source_cost) as cost, 
    coalesce(sum(assignments.recipient_revenue), 0) as revenue, 
    (coalesce(sum(assignments.recipient_revenue), 0) -
              sum(leads.source_cost)) as profit, 
    date_format(leads.updated_at, "%m/%d/%Y") as date 
from `leads` 
left join `assignments` on `assignments`.`lead_id` = `leads`.`id`
                       and `assignments`.`deleted_at` is null 
where leads.updated_at between "2017-08-24 04:00:00"
                           and "2017-08-26 03:59:59" 
group by `date`
```

I need the `sum(leads.source_cost)` to use distinct `leads.id` in my query because a lead can be assigned more than once.

How do I do this? I can't do a group by because I need the group by to use the `date` alias.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN ... ON ... IS NULL` seems like a strange pattern.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 6):

https://tiaashish.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/mysql-sum-for-distinct-rows-with-left-join/

Here is a blog post that describes exactly this situation and provides a very nice solution to it, using a simple formula:

`SUM(leads.source_cost) * COUNT(DISTINCT leads.id) / COUNT(*)`

Comment: As someone who needed this, your answer is the best.

Comment: This is nonsense. It only works when you have just one distinct id. When you have 2, (n * x + m * y) * 2 / (n + m) ≠ x + y

Comment: DON'T USE: this formula doesn't work on all cases, you would be fooled by it when it works on some cases, but then on production, it would result in false values. i.e., consider the result was 6 records: 2, 2 duplicated, 1, 1 unique, all of them have 0 costs except one of the unique, the result is: sum(850) * 4 / 6 = 566.666666667, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches, but one is to use a derived table, to allow two levels of grouping and aggregation.  A derived table is a temporary table that is automatically materialized while the query is running, and automatically destroyed when the query is finished. MySQL calls this a *subquery in the FROM clause*. Here, it's called "x".

```
select 
    sum(x.leads_source_cost) as cost, 
    coalesce(sum(x.assignments_recipient_revenue), 0) as revenue, 
    (coalesce(sum(x.assignments_recipient_revenue), 0) - sum(x.leads_source_cost)) as profit, 
    date_format(x.leads_updated_at, "%m/%d/%Y") as date 
from (
         SELECT 
            l.id AS leads_id, 
            l.source_cost AS leads_source_cost
            SUM(a.recipient_revenue) AS assignments_recipient_revenue,
            l.updated_at AS leads_updated_at
        FROM `leads` l
        left join `assignments` a on a.`lead_id` = l.`id` and a.`deleted_at` is null 
    where leads.updated_at between "2017-08-24 04:00:00" and "2017-08-26 03:59:59"
        GROUP BY l.id
    ) x
group by `date`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the answer

```
select 
    sum(leads.source_cost) as cost, 
    coalesce(sum(assignments.recipient_revenue), 0) as revenue,
```

to

```
select 
    (select round(sum(leads.source_cost)/count(leads.id)))) as cost, 
    coalesce(sum(assignments.recipient_revenue), 0) as revenue,
```

like entering a sub query sum includes 2-3 duplicate values so we divided by no. of duplicates. and round to omit the decimal 0 in result set.

(and did you tried putting id after date  )

```
like group by date to -> group by date , leads.id
```

Comment: Ugh.  Would one really want to have the sum of 1,2,2,2 be only 3?

Comment: Opps, i didn't noticed distinct by "id" . I have edited the answer, hope this one is relevant